# VB 2010 Open Word Document

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, word-2010

I need to open an existing Word document from within my VB 2010 application and detect when the user has closed the document in order to copy that document to a database, whether the user modified it or not.  How do I accomplish this?  Thanks.

Example:

```
'Code here
Dim word as New Word.Application()
Dim doc as New Word.Document()

'open the document here and let the user work on the word document
'detect when user has closed Word
'copy the word document into database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am editing this to show the complete code solution, this also terminates the application.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Class MainWindow
    Private WithEvents doc As Word.Document
    Private app As New Word.Application
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        app.Visible = True
        app.Documents.Add()
        doc = app.Documents(1)
        doc.Activate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub doc_Close() Handles doc.Close
        app.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This does not work.  The Word.Document object doest not have a .Close event.  Only the Word.Application object has one.

Comment: Did you declare the Word.Document "With Events"? I ran this code in VS 2010 with word 2007, it worked fine. I am not using the Office.interop library.

Comment: Now that i have the code infornt of me i see I was wrong about the interop.

Comment: You are on the right track, though....the Word.Application does have a DocumentBeforeClose and DocumentBeforeSave events which serve my purpose.

Comment: You did ask to "detect when the user has closed the document "

Comment: Yes, but I was expecting another event name like onClose or Closing, but DocumentBeforeclose is actually the one I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to create a new document. Maybe this will get you started?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383

Another good example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55685/Word-Automation-using-VB-NET-Part-I

Comment: Excellent tutorial...but is there a way to add a document.OnClosing or similar event to detect when the document has been closed or saved?  If I use a VB 2010 Word template to create the document I have no problems knowing when the document has been closed.  However, I don't see a way to open the document from, let's say, a button.click event and assign a OnClose event of some sorts

Comment: So you want to open a document from a button click assigned to the OnClose event (presumably opening a document once another one closes)?

Comment: I want to click on a button, open a document, and when the document closes detect that the document has been closed so I can then create a code to cope that .docx to a field in a database table

Comment: According to this article, there is a `Document_Close` event that you should be able to handle, although it goes on to say that you can't have conditional code execute based on whether or not they choose "yes", "no", or "cancel" on the save changes dialog. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?569305-Catch-close-event-in-Word

Answer (score 1):

this will work although it may not be the best choice:

1. before open the doc file, get all processes' pid (like the pid in taskmgr). each opened word file has a pid.
2. now, have a thread, check this at certain interval, if the pid does not exist anymore, the doc file is closed.

not a elegant solution, but it works in our project

Comment: Your suggestion kinda answers my next question, which would be how to kill the underlying Word process that stays open when invoking Word from Visual Studio.